# Getting error while running goanalysis_metalinter

Tags: go, linter

I am getting the following error when `commitlint` is enabled for go project, specifically for `goanalysis_metalinter` package

```
bodyclose: failed prerequisites: analysis skipped: errors in package: [/Users/me/Work/go-template/project/svc/pkg/config/config.go:5:2: could not import os (/usr/local/go/src/os/dir.go:8:2: could not import io/fs (/usr/local/go/src/io/fs/fs.go:11:2: could not import internal/oserror
```